# Can optic pits with blind spots be acquired (not congenital)?

Tags: opthalmology, optic-nerve

The [wikipedia page for optic pits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optic_pit) says that they are congenital (ie, birth defects). They are sometimes accompanied by blind spots because there are fewer optic nerves than normal going to the retina. I know of at least one case where the blind spot and optic pit were discovered later in life.

I'm wondering, are conditions like this *always* congenital, or is there any record of such defects being *acquired* later in life, because of disease, poisoning, or something that causes the optic nerves to somehow die or disappear but look similar to the congenital defect?

Comment: Optic pits don't involve a dead nerve or blindness. The link you included says they're asymptomatic, so not sure why you're comparing them to nerve damage that would render you blind in one eye.

Comment: Maybe I can improve the wording in the question or add to it. I mention nerves "missing" for two reasons: 1. The link says: "The most common visual field defects include an enlarged blind spot and a scotoma." 2. In a certain case, doctors at Mass Eye and Ear said that a blind spot in one eye and accompanying optic pit was "probably a birth defect". They pointed to "rake defects" (I think that was the term) in the retina images, and said the nerves were missing.

Comment: I do think you need to clarify. Using language like optic nerves dying takes the question out of the realm of optic pits.